# Powershell sort-object, csv

Tags: powershell

I got two *.csv files.
The first contains this

```
IP, MAC, Name, Comment
10.10.122.1, 66-55-44-33-22-11, testuser1, this is testuser 1
10.10.122.100, 66-55-44-33-22-12, testuser2, this is testuser 2
10.10.122.2, 66-55-44-33-22-13, testuser3, this is testuser 3
10.10.122.4, 66-55-44-33-22-14, testuser4, this is testuser 4
10.10.122.203, 66-55-44-33-22-15, testuser5, this is testuser 5
```

The second one contains the sorted list of the IPs. This was a little bit tricky 'cause you had to add leading zeros for sorting the IPs and then you need to remove the leading zeros. So the file looks like this:

```
10.10.122.1
10.10.122.2
10.10.122.4
10.10.122.100
10.10.122.203
```

How can I get the other attributes e.g. like the suitable MACS for the IPs in the second csv file?

I tried to use where-object but unfortunately I don't know how to compare the IPs and then to link the other attributes for the correct IPs.

Comment: [Why not sort your first csv file?](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/06/23/sorting-ipaddresses-the-powershell-way/) It already has all the information you need?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it doesn't work well. I followed the steps in the tutorial, but somehow the output looks a bit disordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort the original csv:

```
$data = Import-Csv first.csv
$data = $data | Sort-Object {"{0:000}.{1:000}.{2:000}.{3:000}" -f @([int[]]$_.IP.split("."))}
```

Now, since we've treated each octet of the IP as a zero-padded string during sorting, they will be listed in the right order.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't. I got a large list of addresses and the output looks disordered. I sorted the addresses with this
$data | %{"{0:000}.{1:000}.{2:000}.{3:000}" -f @([int[]]$_.IP.split('.'))} | sort | %{"{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f @([int[]]$_.split('.'))}

Linkink the attributes would be easier to understand for me.
Can't I overload "sort-object" to extend it with the sorting code?

Comment: Oh, my bad, you're absolutely right. Just extend the sorting block to use `$_.IP` in place of `$_` and you should be good to go, check the update

Comment: Oh my god. I just can't believe it. I searched hours and hours how to do that properly. I nearl wanted to overload sort-object for that.
Thanks dude. It worked perfectly !